# View requires parameters that I'm trying to input within that view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this view, which essentially is supposed to provide data for this function:

```
public ActionResult AddKorisnik(string Ime, string Prezime, string JMBG, string DatumRodjenja, 
string BrojTelefona, string Email, string Sifra, string KorisnickoIme,char Spol)
{
    Korisnik x = new Korisnik();
    x.Ime = Ime;
    x.Prezime = Prezime;
    x.JMBG = JMBG;
    x.DatumRodjenja = DatumRodjenja;
    x.BrojTelefona = BrojTelefona;
    x.Email = Email;
    x.Sifra = Sifra;
    x.KorisnickoIme = KorisnickoIme;
    x.AdresaId = 1;
    x.Spol = Spol;
    ctx.Korisnici.Add(x);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Prikazi");
}
```

However, when I try to open that view, it gives me the "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter '**Spol' of non-nullable type 'System.Char' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult AddKorisnik** etc etc" error, saying I need to provide all these parameters. Below is the HTML code for the view:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form action="Home/AddKorisnik">
            Ime: <input id="tbIme" type="text" placeholder="Ime korisnika" required />
            Prezime: <input id="tbPrezime" type="text" placeholder="Prezime korisnika" required />
            Spol: <input id="tbSpol" type="text" placeholder="M ili Z" required />
            JMBG: <input id="tbJMBG" type="number" placeholder="Jedinstveni maticni broj" required />
            Datum rodjenja: <input id="tbDatum" type="datetime" placeholder="Datum rodjenja korisnika" required />
            Broj Telefona: <input id="tbTelefon" type="tel" />
            Email: <input id="tbEmail" type="email" placeholder="Email korisnika" required />
            Korisnicko ime: <input id="tbUsername" type="text" placeholder="Korisnicko ime" required />
            Sifra: <input id="tbSifra" type="password" placeholder="Sifra" required />
            Adresa: <input id="tbAdresa" type="text" placeholder="Zasad ID adrese samo" value="1" required/>
            <input id="Dodaj" type="submit" value="AddKorisnik" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you guys need any more info than this let me know.

Comment: Add GET action for method `AddKorisnik` which will be called when loading the view for that form. And, add POST verb to above method so that it would be called when you submit.

Comment: When I add post, it says resource can't be found, do I need something to add in the form action as well? Also can you elaborate on the GET part?

Comment: I've posted an answer to create GET/POST action in your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved

Had to create a method, which opens the view, and then have the view's button invoke the method that takes the necessary parameters, I have no idea how I overlooked it, I guess I was sleepy.

```
 public ActionResult DodajKorisnika()
        {
            return View("Dodaj");
        }
```

This opens up the view "Dodaj" which I posted above, which in its definition has:

```
<form action="Snimi" method="post">
<input id="Dodaj" type="submit" value="Snimi" />
```

Which invokes

```
public ActionResult Snimi(string Ime, string Prezime, string JMBG, string DatumRodjenja, string BrojTelefona,
            string Email, string Sifra, string KorisnickoIme,char Spol)
        {

            Korisnik x = new Korisnik();
            x.Ime = Ime;
            x.Prezime = Prezime;
            x.JMBG = JMBG;
            x.DatumRodjenja = DatumRodjenja;
            x.BrojTelefona = BrojTelefona;
            x.Email = Email;
            x.Sifra = Sifra;
            x.KorisnickoIme = KorisnickoIme;
            x.AdresaId = 1;
            x.Spol = Spol;
            ctx.Korisnici.Add(x);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Prikazi");
        }
```

Comment: Answers go in the ANSWER section, not the QUESTION. I have rolled back you changes (edit this to explain how you solved it)

Comment: Ok sorry, I didn't know how to mark it solved, it's also not letting me to mark it as solved

Comment: Its a self answer - you need to wait 2 days and then you can accept it (but how do you think this poor quality answer without any code could help anyone else)

Comment: I'll add full code, its 4 AM and I'm tired, spent 2 hours banging my head wiht this issue

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot. Try putting `name` attribute on all controls corresponding to parameters to function:

Like for `Ime` and `Prezime`:

```
Ime:     <input name="Ime" id="tbIme" type="text" placeholder="Ime korisnika" required />
Prezime: <input name="Prezime" id="tbPrezime" type="text" 
    placeholder="Prezime korisnika" required />
```

Add `[HttpPost]` attribute on method `AddKorisnik` as pointed by @AkashKC in the comment to question.

**EDIT:-** Well here is a sample I quickly strapped:

*Controller*

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddKorisnik()
{
    //FOR DEBUGGING ONLY YOU CAN REMOVE THIS
    ViewBag.HasData = false;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddKorisnik(string Ime, string Prezime, string JMBG, 
string DatumRodjenja,
    string BrojTelefona, string Email, string Sifra, string KorisnickoIme, char Spol)
{
    var x = new Korisnik
    {
        Ime = Ime,
        Prezime = Prezime,
        JMBG = JMBG,
        DatumRodjenja = DatumRodjenja,
        BrojTelefona = BrojTelefona,
        Email = Email,
        Sifra = Sifra,
        KorisnickoIme = KorisnickoIme,
        AdresaId = 1,
        Spol = Spol
    };

    //THIS IS JUST TO CHECK THAT WE GET ALL VALUES BACK IN POST
    var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var xStr = js.Serialize(x);
    ViewBag.Data = xStr;
    ViewBag.HasData = true;
    ////////////////
    return View();
}
```

*View*

```
<form action="AddKorisnik" method="post">
    Ime: <input id="tbIme" name="Ime" type="text" placeholder="Ime korisnika" required /><br />
    Prezime: <input name="Prezime" id="tbPrezime" type="text" placeholder="Prezime korisnika" required /><br />
    Spol: <input id="tbSpol" name="Spol" maxlength="1" type="text" placeholder="M ili Z" required /><br />
    JMBG: <input id="tbJMBG" name="JMBG" type="number" placeholder="Jedinstveni maticni broj" required /><br />
    Datum rodjenja: <input id="tbDatum" name="DatumRodjenja" type="datetime" placeholder="Datum rodjenja korisnika" required /><br />
    Broj Telefona: <input id="tbTelefon" name="BrojTelefona" type="tel" /><br />
    Email: <input id="tbEmail" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email korisnika" required /><br />
    Korisnicko ime: <input id="tbUsername" type="text" name="Korisnickolme" placeholder="Korisnicko ime" required /><br />
    Sifra: <input id="tbSifra" type="password" placeholder="Sifra" name="Sifra" required /><br />
    Adresa: <input id="tbAdresa" type="text" placeholder="Zasad ID adrese samo" name="AdresaId" value="1" required /><br />
    <input id="Dodaj" type="submit" value="AddKorisnik" />
</form>

//THIS IS FOR DEBUGGING ONLY    
@if (ViewBag.HasData)
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Data)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add `GET` action for the method `AddKorisnik` which will be called when you load view which has that form.

Your `GET` action would be like this :

```
[HttpGet] // This attribute ensured that it's GET action
public ActionResult AddKorisnik()
{
    return View();
}
```

Now, your method posted in above question should be decorated with `HttpPost` attribute in following way :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddKorisnik(string Ime, string Prezime, string JMBG, string DatumRodjenja, 
string BrojTelefona, string Email, string Sifra, string KorisnickoIme,char Spol)
{
    Korisnik x = new Korisnik();
    x.Ime = Ime;
    x.Prezime = Prezime;
    x.JMBG = JMBG;
    x.DatumRodjenja = DatumRodjenja;
    x.BrojTelefona = BrojTelefona;
    x.Email = Email;
    x.Sifra = Sifra;
    x.KorisnickoIme = KorisnickoIme;
    x.AdresaId = 1;
    x.Spol = Spol;
    ctx.Korisnici.Add(x);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Prikazi");
}
```

After this, add method attribute in form tag in view side :

```
<form action="Home/AddKorisnik" method="POST">
```

To correctly pass your value, you should rename your html control id exactly matching with field passed in the method as @TheVillageIdiot suggested.

**Recommended way :**

I would recommend you to create `ViewModel`(a class which binds your UI with controller) so that you can use Razor syntax in strongly typed way. 
You can learn more about it from [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/viewmodels)

Comment: It gave me the same issues. When I add the HttpPost tag, it gives me 404 error, and even adding the method=Post to the View still gives me the same error. I'm doing this for a college project so I was just following video instructions, pretty new to MVC and razor. Like, I understand the error it's telling me, but I don't know why it doesn't let me input the values first.

Comment: Your view is displaying fine or you getting error when loading view?